# How to delete all rows in a table

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an automated script written in C# for adding data to a table that seems to work correctly and now want to create a test cleanup to remove all data that has been entered.

I'm looking to loop through the table, deleting all entries that are visible.

The delete icon in the table has the following HTML -

```
<a class="dxbButton_Office2010Silver dxgvCommandColumnItem_Office2010Silver dxgv__cci dxbButtonSys" data-args="[['Delete',0],1]" id="GridView_ExchangeHolidays_DXCBtn2" href="javascript:;" style="font-size: 0pt;"><img title="Delete" class="dx-vam" src="/Images/deletegray.png" alt="Delete" style="height:16px;width:16px;" id="GridView_ExchangeHolidays_DXCBtn2Img"></a>
```

The XPath for the button is-

first button - //*[@id="GridView_ExchangeHolidays_DXCBtn2Img"]

next button - //*[@id="GridView_ExchangeHolidays_DXCBtn4Img"]

and so on..

Any ideas? My initial thought was to count how many rows are present and then for each entry, click the delete button but just not sure how to go about this. Something along the lines of-

```
        int rowCount = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='GridView_ExchangeHolidays_DXMainTable']/tbody/tr")).Count;

        for(int i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
        {
            //Code to delete rows here
        }
```

Comment: Post your HTML in your question.

Comment: To delete rows, you have to start from the last. Otherwise when you delete #0, then #1 is already #0 and you delete #1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to count how many rows are present for *deletion* and then for each entry invoke `Click()` on the *Delete* button as follows :

```
int rowCount = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[@class='dxbButton_Office2010Silver dxgvCommandColumnItem_Office2010Silver dxgv__cci dxbButtonSys']/img[@class='dx-vam' and starts-with(@id,'GridView_ExchangeHolidays_DXCBtn')]")).Count;
for(int i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='dxbButton_Office2010Silver dxgvCommandColumnItem_Office2010Silver dxgv__cci dxbButtonSys']/img[@class='dx-vam' and starts-with(@id,'GridView_ExchangeHolidays_DXCBtn')]")).Click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the deleted images is dynamic below code wont work

```
int rowCount = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='GridView_ExchangeHolidays_DXMainTable']/tbody/tr")).Count;

    for(int i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
    {
        driver.findelement(By.Xpath(".//*[@class='dxbButton_Office2010Silver dxgvCommandColumnItem_Office2010Silver dxgv__cci dxbButtonSys']")).click();
        //if delete conformation presents handle using alert method.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are following the right approach. You should go ahead with this. Please find below the code snippet which you can add in your code.

```
int rowCount = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='GridView_ExchangeHolidays_DXMainTable']/tbody/tr")).Count;

    for(int i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='GridView_ExchangeHolidays_DXMainTable']/tbody/tr[i]/img[@title='Delete']/..a]")).Click();
    }
```